# How to print a long string in multiple lines in Python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, logging, printing

I recently came across python f-string. Let, there is a long line of string like

```
string = 'L4qrGFHK8eDA9Vy05gNH7inxfaVpPZH3i9pRdWScalA0pIGHKGqUEXejplKiYaCNizbiKH72LoQaoz1pQH9caDfAX5xtfQAZEri7QGkvxMAJWXsjPEPLQhTtTvvhDR1tMM9zX8Dd0l15bBW1Q3VQReOsbP5AQmMOK9GV0WYPZ015sg7tg8JKOs7hFJfD8bdpUQgWbGrxSdS95PnBTf4P2nTWWLrWzo3DQNyXHs29R6MZ92qqfPLGL8SSQNchWyo4V9NoHdAHDo5TdPf6VmNQaQAl9HKLVawTTg379plHr81YYEoojzstCSPh3jAy9W4dmjTLrBUxzA9tK5UlHKMGx7IYieNGfXBKTaCegdJOUubZPajkp0KY8OcpHxlaVFVdIPi58n6VH7evAomB'
```

I want to print this string like this:

L4qrGFHK8eDA9Vy05gNH7inxfaVpPZH3i9pRdWSc
alA0pIGHKGqUEXejplKiYaCNizbiKH72LoQaoz1p
QH9caDfAX5xtfQAZEri7QGkvxMAJWXsjPEPLQhTt
TvvhDR1tMM9zX8Dd0l15bBW1Q3VQReOsbP5AQmMO
K9GV0WYPZ015sg7tg8JKOs7hFJfD8bdpUQgWbGrx
SdS95PnBTf4P2nTWWLrWzo3DQNyXHs29R6MZ92qq
fPLGL8SSQNchWyo4V9NoHdAHDo5TdPf6VmNQaQAl
9HKLVawTTg379plHr81YYEoojzstCSPh3jAy9W4d
mjTLrBUxzA9tK5UlHKMGx7IYieNGfXBKTaCegdJO
UubZPajkp0KY8OcpHxlaVFVdIPi58n6VH7evAomB

And I want to use F-strings. I have tried left alignment like

```
print(f"{string}:<{40}")
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you use textwrap for:

```
import textwrap
string = 'L4qrGFHK8eDA9Vy05gNH7inxfaVpPZH3i9pRdWScalA0pIGHKGqUEXejplKiYaCNizbiKH72LoQaoz1pQH9caDfAX5xtfQAZEri7QGkvxMAJWXsjPEPLQhTtTvvhDR1tMM9zX8Dd0l15bBW1Q3VQReOsbP5AQmMOK9GV0WYPZ015sg7tg8JKOs7hFJfD8bdpUQgWbGrxSdS95PnBTf4P2nTWWLrWzo3DQNyXHs29R6MZ92qqfPLGL8SSQNchWyo4V9NoHdAHDo5TdPf6VmNQaQAl9HKLVawTTg379plHr81YYEoojzstCSPh3jAy9W4dmjTLrBUxzA9tK5UlHKMGx7IYieNGfXBKTaCegdJOUubZPajkp0KY8OcpHxlaVFVdIPi58n6VH7evAomB'
# print("{string}:<40")
print(textwrap.fill(string, 40))

L4qrGFHK8eDA9Vy05gNH7inxfaVpPZH3i9pRdWSc
alA0pIGHKGqUEXejplKiYaCNizbiKH72LoQaoz1p
QH9caDfAX5xtfQAZEri7QGkvxMAJWXsjPEPLQhTt
TvvhDR1tMM9zX8Dd0l15bBW1Q3VQReOsbP5AQmMO
K9GV0WYPZ015sg7tg8JKOs7hFJfD8bdpUQgWbGrx
SdS95PnBTf4P2nTWWLrWzo3DQNyXHs29R6MZ92qq
fPLGL8SSQNchWyo4V9NoHdAHDo5TdPf6VmNQaQAl
9HKLVawTTg379plHr81YYEoojzstCSPh3jAy9W4d
mjTLrBUxzA9tK5UlHKMGx7IYieNGfXBKTaCegdJO
UubZPajkp0KY8OcpHxlaVFVdIPi58n6VH7evAomB
```